# Restcomm USSD Gateway Installation (Community version)

Tags: java, jboss, gateway, ussd, restcomm

I want to install Restcomm USSD Gateway on my Windows (or Linux). But I couldn't find any documentation for latest releases (https://github.com/RestComm/ussdgateway)

I did a **clean build** with **maven** and I have got JAR files. But I don't know how to (and which JARS) deploy on WILDFLY or JBOSS. There not pre-exists JBOSS.5.1.0 in latest releases. I asked some docs from RESTCOMM but they said that they support only for purchases.

If anyone here has implemented Restcomm USSD Gateway or has any information, please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link https://github.com/RestComm/ussdgateway/blob/master/docs/installationguide/sources-asciidoc/src/main/asciidoc/USSD_Gateway_Installation_Guide.adoc. It has the step by step on how to install and configure the USSD GW